# Did the early church allow statues and images in church?

Tags: church-history, early-church, art, veneration, statues

Protestants are against having statues and images and often quote Exodus 20:4, but Catholics and Orthodox Christians have beautiful statues and images in their church, but did the Early Church Fathers have statues and images in church and did they support the usage of images and statues in the church?

Comment: The real problem with this particular question is that the Early Church was under persecution during the first four centuries and churches rarely existed in the sense that we know them now. Early Christians often met in homes or Catacombs. [Early Church](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity) is generally reckoned by church historians to begin with the ministry of Jesus (27–30) and end with the First Council of Nicaea (325). It is typically divided into two periods: the Apostolic Age (c. 30–100, when the first apostles were still alive) and the Ante-Nicene Period (c. 100–325)

Comment: Related: [What was the ante-Nicene Fathers' view on image veneration?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91037/what-was-the-ante-nicene-fathers-view-on-image-veneration)